# VHDL & GTKWAVE: how to get a bus of "u" bit values to display in the color red instead of green?

Tags: vhdl

If I display this bus in verilog its all red x's:

```
// VERILOG: unassigned signal sigx
reg [15:0] sigx; //displays as RED in gtkwaves
```

If i display this bus in vhdl its all green u's which is really easy to miss:

```
-- unassigned signal sigu
signal sigu : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --displays as GREEN?! in gtkwaves
```

How to properly configure gtkwaves for VHDL such that it has the same behavior as verilog by displaying unknown values in the color red instead of green?  namely to map coloring scheme of 'x' to 'u' in the vcd file.

(strangely, gtkwave displays a single bit that unassigned in red... its just when you make a bus out of them they show up as green in vhdl...)

Comment: see "color_u" parameter   https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-gtkwaverc/ ... still a bit sketchy about how to modify gtkwaverc file on a windows PC...

Comment: is there a search order for finding gtkwaverc file?  like for instance, could i modify my gtkwave's install directory to set a global default for one of the parameters in this file without overriding it in my home directory.  I'm also a little bit confused about which directory is my HOME directory on windows 10.

Comment: [In the GTKWave manual](http://gtkwave.sourceforge.net/gtkwave.pdf) Appendix B: .gtkwaverc Variable Reference "A difference in Windows to be aware of is that the default (if unspecified) .gtkwaverc file is known as gtkwave.iniand resides in the current working directory." in Appendix A: Command Line Options Reference can also specify the file with `-r,--rcfile <filename>` or simply as the last command line parameter after either or both the dump file and save file.

Answer (score 0):

Work around using perl script to convert arrays of 'U' into arrays of 'X' in vcd file, then it looks more like a verilog vcd instead of vhdl vcd file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$ovcd = "waves.vcd";
$nvcd = "nwaves.vcd";

print "reading: $ovcd\n";
print "writing: $nvcd\n";

open(I, $ovcd) || die("cannot read file: $ovcd");
open(O, ">$ncd") || die("cannot write file: $nvcd");
while(<I>) {
    $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ /^b(\S+)\s/) {
         $ovalue = $1;
         $nvalue = $ovalue;
         $nvalue =~ s/U/X/g;
         $line   =~ s/$ovalue/$nvalue/;    
    }
    print O $line;
}
close(I);
close(O);
```

Comment: Consider using ghdl's GHW dump file format which will display any type and value. Arrays become indexed elements, records become named elements, enumerated types show enumerations.  'U' and 'X' are of unique colors and you can map colors individually in the rcfile.